# Overriding default calendar to show posts from a category

Tags: categories, query, sql, filters, calendar

I'm trying to modify the default WP calendar (get_calendar()) so that it shows posts from a specific category and then use that as a shortcode.

Here's what I've done:

Copied across the get_calendar() function from the core (from wp-includes) into my child theme's functions.php file. In order to make it an 'independent' calendar, I changed the name of the get_calendar() function to osu_get_calendar() and have successfully hardcoded the calendar into my template using osu_get_calendar();

Now I'm trying to get my hands a bit dirtier and do the following:

1) Restrict the posts shown in the calendar to a specific category (while maintaining the previous and next navigation so visitors can search through those posts by month)

2) Make it into a shortcode so my client can essentially embed a calendar with posts from a category they choose at the bottom of their posts.

I'm stuck on 1) at the moment as it looks like I need to modify the SQL queries so that it pulls posts from a specific category. Looking at the code below from the get_calendar() function, how would I filter the posts pulled from the database so that they are from a specific category? There are other SQL queries in there, but hopefully someone can help me with this one for now:

```
$previous = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(post_date) AS month, YEAR(post_date) AS year
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_date < '$thisyear-$thismonth-01'
        AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
            ORDER BY post_date DESC
            LIMIT 1");
    $next = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT  DISTINCT MONTH(post_date) AS month, YEAR(post_date) AS year
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_date >   '$thisyear-$thismonth-01'
        AND MONTH( post_date ) != MONTH( '$thisyear-$thismonth-01' )
        AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
            ORDER   BY post_date ASC
            LIMIT 1");
```

Thanks,

osu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were starting on the right track but you had several bits of WordPress hookage you still needed to add. An approach I like to use is to encapsulate a call to `get_calendar()` in a class so we can use the low-level `'query'` hook but only use for it for the one call.

So I wrote up an example which you can drop into your theme's `functions.php` file *(or in a `.php` file for a plugin you might be writing)* using a class I named `YourSite_Category_Calendar()`, and here is how you'd call it in place of your call to `get_calendar()`:

```php
$cc = new YourSite_Category_Calendar('your-category');
echo $cc->get_calendar();
```

And here's the code for the class:

```php
<?php 

class YourSite_CategoryCalendar {
  var $category;
  var $initial;
  var $echo;
  static function on_load() {
    add_shortcode('category-calendar',array(__CLASS__,'shortcode'));
    add_action('init',array(__CLASS__,'init'));
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('^events/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/?$',
      'index.php?post_type=event&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&category_name=$matches[4]',
      'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);  // Remove this after you've got it working
  }
  static function shortcode($attributes) {
    $attributes = wp_parse_args($attributes,array(
      'category' => false,
    ));
    $cc = new YourSite_CategoryCalendar($attributes['category']);
    echo $cc->get_calendar();
  }
  static function init() {
    register_post_type('event',array(
      'hierarchical'    => true,
      'label'          => 'Events',
      'public'          => true,
      'show_ui'         => true,
      'query_var'       => 'event',
      'rewrite'         => array('slug' => 'events'),
      'supports'        => array('title','editor','custom-fields'),
      'taxonomies'      => array('category'),
    ));
  }
  function __construct($category,$initial=true,$echo=true) {
    $this->category = $category;
    $this->initial = $initial;
    $this->echo = $echo;
  }
  function get_calendar() {
    add_filter('query',array(&$this,'query'));
    ob_start();
    get_calendar($this->category,$this->initial,$this->echo);
    $calendar = ob_get_clean();
    remove_filter('query',array(&$this,'query'));
    list($header,$body) = explode('<tbody>',$calendar);
    $find = '#(href="http://[^/]+)(/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/)#';
    $replace = '$1/events$2'.$this->category.'/"';
    $body = preg_replace($find,$replace,$body);
    return "{$header}<tbody>{$body}";
  }
  function query($query) {
    if ($this->category) {
      global $wpdb;
      $find = "FROM {$wpdb->posts}\\s+WHERE";
      $add =<<<SQL
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} calendar_term_relationship ON calendar_term_relationship.object_id={$wpdb->posts}.ID
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} calendar_term_taxonomy ON calendar_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=calendar_term_relationship.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} calendar_term ON calendar_term.term_id=calendar_term_taxonomy.term_id
WHERE calendar_term_taxonomy.taxonomy='category' AND calendar_term.slug='%s' AND
SQL;
      $replace = "FROM {$wpdb->posts} {$add} ";
      $query = preg_replace("#{$find}#Us",$replace,$query);
      $query = preg_replace("#post_type\s*=\s*'post'#","post_type='event'",$query);
      $query = $wpdb->prepare($query,$this->category);
    }
    return $query;
  }
}
YourSite_CategoryCalendar::on_load();
```

### UPDATE

Based on the comments I've added the URLs rewriting needed as well as a shortcode you'd call like this:

```
[category-calendar category="party"]
```

Comment: Hi Mike, this looks extremely useful (not only for this project, but as an approach for future projects). Many thanks for taking the time to share your knowledge - I shouldn't come up against any problems using it with a custom post type right? I intend to use it with an 'Events' post type with a hierarchical custom taxonomy...

Comment: @Osu - You'll have to search the query for `post_type = 'post'` and replace with ` post_type = 'event'` but other than that, no problem *(btw, don't forgot to vote up and select a best answer when people go to the effort to help you here. :)*

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - thanks for this, just voted for the answer. I just tried this out, but using this: <?php $cc = new YourSite_Category_Calendar('news'); echo $cc->get_calendar(); ?> came up with both Blog and News category posts in the calendar (on my localhost, I only have these two categories for posts). Any idea why?

Comment: @Osu - I know it's obvious but I have to ask, are the categories exclusive or to have have posts that have both categories?  Also, are you using any plugins that may be conflicting with this?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - No, posts aren't sharing a category. This is a vanilla install with only WP Dummy Content installed to see how content looks in the site. I'll see if that's conflicting, but I doubt it is considering it only adds content and a custom field

Comment: @Osu - I just tried `echo "\n{$query}\n\n";` before `return $query;` to see in view source what SQL was generated. With a category of `'dark-beer'` this is the SQL queries generated: http://pastebin.com/7J1xxr0w and unless I'm missing something there is no way that they can pull anything other than the dark beer posts. Please try to same on your and if you can't diagnose the problem post the resultant SQL to a pastebin so you can show me the generated SQL in a link. My bet is some plugin is somehow adding the '`blog'` category to your SQL query. Or maybe it's calling the `'get_calendar'` hook?

Comment: @Osu - I tested the query directly on MySQL and it gave me only those with a category of `'dark-beer'`. When I removed the `'dark-beer'` criteria it gave me a lot more posts.  I checked the *"WP Dummy Content" plugin and it doesn't do anything to affect this. Do you have any code in your theme's `functions.php` file that might be hooking the SQL query?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - thanks for taking the time to do this, it's much appreciated. I can confirm that the SQL query has <code>calendar_term.slug='news'</code> only, no mention of <code>'blog'</code>. Do you think there's a caching issue going on here? Nothing in my functions.php, other than a few overrides of widget registrations and <code>the_excerpt();</code> (my theme is a child theme of TwentyTen btw). When you click on a link in the calendar, I assume you're reaching a page like this right? http://localhost:8888/?m=20110116 - that's where I'm seeing both category posts

Comment: @Osu - So the calendar is generating the data correctly, but the pages that are loaded by links from the calendar are not working like you want? Nothing in your question asked for that! That's a different issue entirely. <sigh> You should probably ask another question on the site asking how filter year-month-day pages by specific type. Also, are you not using pretty permalinks?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - apologies, I thought that was clear from the part of my question saying I want to show posts from a specific category in the calendar. I won't waste your time any more other than to ask in what context I would use the code you provided? I genuinely thought that your code is what I'd need for generating a calendar with links to posts from a specific category...yes, I'm using pretty permalinks

Comment: @Osu - Okay, I went ahead and did all the other stuff you wanted too. You owe me. :-)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - I certainly do owe you! Can I buy you a virtual beer? PM me if so - going to have a look at getting those month navigations working now, but this is a great help :)

Comment: @Osu - No worries! The best virtual beer you can give me are up votes whenever you see one of my answers here on the site that helps you. :)